# T-SQL Case When Exists Query Not Producing Expected Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, exists

I've put together a query which should show every record which has events before and after a selected date. With an extra column added that will be set to True/False if the record has events before date and the same for if the record has events after the second date.

Problem is I know there are records in the events table with have events before the first date and not after the second date but they don't appear in my query. Only results that are True for both come out of the query. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DeviceName,dPhone,DSIMID,  Vehicles.reg, DeviceID,
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT eventID FROM [events] WHERE [events].sysdatetime < 
'2018-09-05 11:46:00.000')
THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' 
END AS [WasReportingBeforeDate],
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT eventID FROM [events] WHERE [events].sysdatetime > 
'2018-09-05 11:46:00.000')
THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS [WasReportingAfterDate]
FROM [Devices]
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Vehicles.DevID = Devices.DevID
INNER JOIN [events] ON Devices.DevID = [events].DeviceID;
```

Current Output Example is:

```
Z3243   1  1 AA05 AAA 1 True    True
```

Expected Output:

```
Z3243   1  1 AA05 AAA 1 True    False
```

There is no data for this record more recent than the second date so it should return false

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Those subqueries are not linked to the outer query. So `DeviceID` filter is not applied to them. And `DISTINCT ` is saying that `event` should not be joined that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't correlating your `EXISTS`, so if any record exists in the table with `[events].sysdatetime > '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'` then your `EXISTS` will always return true.

You want something like this:

```
...
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM [events] e2
                  WHERE e2.sysdatetime > '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'
                  AND e2.eventID = e.eventID) --here
...
FROM [Devices] d
INNER JOIN Vehicles v ON b.DevID = d.DevID
INNER JOIN [events] e ON d.DevID = e.DeviceID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break the query into 2 separate queries and use union all to return the result set back together again. If you need a flag to determine the Events before you could hard code this into the below queries.

```
   ;WITH EventsBefore AS 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           DeviceName,
           dPhone,
           DSIMID,
           Vehicles.reg,
           DeviceID,
    FROM [Devices]
         INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Vehicles.DevID = Devices.DevID
         INNER JOIN [events] ON Devices.DevID = [events].DeviceID
         INNER JOIN lastEvent ON Devices.DevID = lastEvent.devID;
    WHERE [events].sysdatetime < '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'

    )

     ,EventsAfter AS 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           DeviceName,
           dPhone,
           DSIMID,
           Vehicles.reg,
           DeviceID,
    FROM [Devices]
         INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Vehicles.DevID = Devices.DevID
         INNER JOIN [events] ON Devices.DevID = [events].DeviceID
         INNER JOIN lastEvent ON Devices.DevID = lastEvent.devID;
    WHERE WHERE [events].sysdatetime > '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'

    )

    SELECT * FROM EventsBefore
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM EventsAfter
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of join to `events` and feel free to remove redundant `DISTINCT`
2. Put join predicate into subqueries which are missing it now

like that:

```
SELECT DeviceName,dPhone,DSIMID,  Vehicles.reg, DeviceID,
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [events] e 
    WHERE e.sysdatetime < '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'
    AND e.DeviceID = Devices.DevID)
  THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' 
END AS [WasReportingBeforeDate],
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [events] e 
    WHERE e.sysdatetime > '2018-09-05 11:46:00.000'
    AND e.DeviceID = Devices.DevID)
THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS [WasReportingAfterDate]
FROM [Devices]
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Vehicles.DevID = Devices.DevID
```